# Gitlab CE Continuous Integration build node/angular app and deploy dist folder to server

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've spent countless hours trying to understand how to do this correctly.

I have a nodejs application with angular front-end which are both contained in the same project.

I would simply like to have Gitlab CE CI build the project and then copy the resulting dist folder and package.json file to the production server and restart

I have a shared gitlab runner setup and was able to successfully configure the ssh runner.

Using the Gitlab runner ssh I was able to  copy the entire project to the production server but cannot get it to build (plus I really don't want to have all files on the server, just the production required files.

what am I missing. do you use a docker runner with a node image to build the project and they scp files to the production server?

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you already state the solution.

I would recommend looking into [Job Artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) to build your application in a Docker-based build job and upload the production files as an artifact.

The next job could then deploy (by scp or ssh+wget/curl) the artifact files to your production server and restart the webserver.